# arial font face issue with mozilla

Tags: css, browser, font-face, mozilla

I need your help in solving a very strange issue.
We need to make "Arial" to be 100% similar in all browsers. To do that we used @font-face and used a different file name for Arial.
It works fine in all browsers (pixel by pixel similar), however in some machines it is behaving different .... all systems have same configuration and browser versions.
issue seems to be with Mozilla so far.
I have tried everything but no result.
I used 'font squirrel' to convert fonts (basic/optimal/expert).
here is my CSS.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'conduit_arial';
src: url('../Helper/Fonts/conduit_arial.eot');
src: url('../Helper/Fonts/conduit_arial.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../Helper/Fonts/conduit_arial.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('../Helper/Fonts/conduit_arial.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../Helper/Fonts/conduit_arial.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../Helper/Fonts/conduit_arial.svg#conduit_arial') format('svg'); 
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

we used different name in font face and different file name also so that browser do not load Arial from system fonts.
Friends kindly help me to identify the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Is the issue that the font is behaving differently on different machines, but the same browser? or that the font does not load at all causing it to be different?

Comment: font is behaving different in different machines but same browser

Comment: is the font completely wrong? can you provide an example of the differences?

Comment: some browsers are showing "times new roman" (not calling he font at all) and few machines are showing extra space between characters, while 80% of the machines are displaying it 100% correct

Comment: for the machines that do not show at all, can you see an error in the network tab using the developer tools? If so, what is the error? For those with the extra space between characters, this could just be a resolution/machine rendering issue.

Comment: same resolution in all machines :(

Comment: Ok, well, can you see the error in the network tab for the fonts that do not load?

Comment: i cant post the image is it require reputation 10,  well the network tb shows the following error "downladable font: file les than 4 bytes ... "

Comment: when you navigate to the URL of the font on the machines that do not work what do you get?

Comment: when navigate to font, it works

Comment: I think the font file on those machines is being blocked by the browser because it is less than 4 bytes. Not sure why it would only happen on certain machines though. I'm not sure it is a specific font-face problem, maybe try widening your question with the detail you have given me in the comments.

Comment: Now that your reputation is 11, you can edit your post to add images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is not posible at 100%. Let me explain you why:

1. Arial could be probably the most wide spread font. Let's say that this doesn't make us feel safe.
2. As you've done, you can be sure to load the same font by using font-face and a diferent name for the font. Can you be sure now? not completly, as there are browsers that may not support font-face...
3. Let's say you don't need to support browsers older than ie9. Now you must be sure... No again! Different browsers and different OS's have diferent ways of dealing with fonts. Windows has the ClearType engine for rendering and is different from OS X's engine (more info here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/)
4. Let's say you only need to support Windows 7 and 8. Now you must be sure... No again! Different browsers may render the fonts in different ways. For example, older versions of Chrome didn't have a very good antialiasing on windows. Their fonts were sharper but uglier!

**My advice:** As you can see, there are many things you can't control... Still, there are some good-practices that you could follow so as to diminish problems. Try to give exact pixel dimensions to your fonts, even when you are using em's and specially for smaller font sizes. For example, use `0.875em` rather than `0.9em`, avoid fonts designed for printing, specially in content (like the commonly used Helvetica) and make wise use of font fallbacking.